# MongoError: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ssl

I am trying to connect my node server with mongodb with ssl options enabled.

## mongod.conf

```
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
  enabled: true

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: XX
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1,XXX.XX.XX.XXX
  ssl:
    mode: requireSSL
    PEMKeyFile: /etc/ssl/PEMKEYFILE.pem
    PEMKeyPassword: "PASSWORDFORPEM"
    CAFile: /etc/ssl/CAFILE.pem

security:
  authorization: enabled

replication:
  oplogSizeMB: 1024
  replSetName: "REPLSET"
```

## node server conf file

```
MONGO_URL: '<pathToMongoDb>/<db>',
        MONGO_REPLICA_SET_READ_PREFERENCE: 'nearest',
        MONGO_REPLICA_SET: {
            ssl: true,
            sslValidate: true,
            sslKey: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/mongodb.pem'),
            sslCert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/mongodb.pem'),
            sslCa: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/CAFILE.pem'),
            replicaSet: 'REPLSET',
            auto_reconnect: false,
            poolSize: 24,
            socketOptions: {
                keepAlive: 1000,
                connectTimeoutMS: 30000
            }
        },
        MONGO_SERVER: {
            ssl: true,
            sslValidate: false,
            checkServerIdentity: false,
            sslKey: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/mongodb.pem'),
            sslCert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/mongodb.pem'),
            sslCA: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/CAFILE.pem'),
            poolSize: 24,
            socketOptions: { keepAlive: 300000, connectTimeoutMS: 30000 },
            reconnectTries: Number.MAX_VALUE,
            reconnectInterval: 1000
        },
        MONGO_CHECK_SERVER_IDENTITY: false,
```

## mongoose file

```
mongoose.connect(config.MONGO_URL,{
  db: {
      native_parser: true,
      readPreference: config.MONGO_REPLICA_SET_READ_PREFERENCE
  },
  server: config.MONGO_SERVER,
  replset: config.MONGO_REPLICA_SET,
  user: config.MONGO_USER,
  pass: config.MONGO_PASSWORD,
  auth: {
      authdb: config.MONGO_AUTHDB
  }
```

})

I have created the CA certificate and and signing certificate but the node server is returning me with the error : `MongoError: failed to connect to server [XX.XXX.XXX.XX:port] on first connect MongoError: self signed certificate in certificate chain` I am able to connect to the mongo using shell using the following command

`mongo XX.XX.XX.XXX:XX/<db> -u <user> -p <pass> --authenticationDatabase=admin --ssl --sslPEMKeyFile=/etc/ssl/PEMKEYFILE.pem --sslCAFile /etc/ssl/CAFILE.pem --sslAllowInvalidHostnames`

Please suggest me where I am going wrong.  Thanks

Comment: This has nothing to do with the client. It's a server configuration issue, and as such is off-topic for StackOverflow. Please ask on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com) instead.

Comment: I am not able to connect through node application and able to connect through shell, that means there is something missing in it. Please if you have any idea then answer the question as I am wondering for last two days.

Comment: It's a server issue. Please post on the correct site for server problems and someone will help you there.

Comment: posted there.. Thanks for the reference

Answer (score 2):

This specific error happens when you have a self signed CA.

With the mongo 3.3.4 driver it's connecting for me with

```
var userName = encodeURIComponent("emailAddress=myemail@example.com,CN=notsameasca,OU=notsameasca,O=my.fqdn.com,L=HomeCity,ST=HomeState,C=XX");
const MongoDBURI = `mongodb://${userName}@dev.vm:27017?authMechanism=MONGODB-X509&tls=true`;


MongoClient.connect(url,{
        tlsAllowInvalidHostnames: true,
        tlsAllowInvalidCertificates: true,
        tlsCertificateKeyFile: "./ssl/keyandcert.pem",
      })
```

When connecting to the server from a command line it happens too unless you use the `--tlsAllowInvalidCertificates` switch.

`mongo -port 27017 --tls --tlsCertificateKeyFile mongoadmin.pem --tlsAllowInvalidCertificates`

You need to specify `--tlsAllowInvalidCertificates` in your client connection.

This is all quite tricky to get right, good luck... you'll need it.